HG8120H будет работать в режиме 2 Гигабит с 2 LAN суммарно? если оптика поддерживает
Оптика подключена в HG8120H, в нем же 2 выхода LAN, если на один LAN будет Гигабит входящего, на другой Гигабит исходящего трафика, сам оптический терминал потянет это?
